# Fields not queried in same order as Access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two simple VBA functions in MS Access to copy and paste an entry. However, when I copy the entry, the fields are not in the same order. I have ten fields in the access table, ordered from 1-10, but when the data is copied is ends up 1-8,10,9. The field in position 9 was newly added field so my thought is that there is a field index and its ID is actually 10 instead of 9, but I see no place to change that.

Unfortunately, I'm no expert and also not the one who built this Access database so I am hesitant to change to much about the code for risk of breaking other things.

Here is the copy function for reference:

```
Private Sub Copy_Click()
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
Set RS = Me.Recordset
With RSC
    .FindFirst "[User] = '" & Active_User & "'"
    If .NoMatch Then
        .AddNew
    Else
        .Edit
    End If
    For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        .Fields(i).Value = RS.Fields(i).Value
    Next
    .Update
End With
Me.Paste.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to force Access to use a different field order, but if source and destination have the same columns, access the fields via name.

```
For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
    fieldName = RS.Fields(i).name
    .Fields(fieldName).Value = RS.Fields(fieldName).Value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the field in question is a numeric field, you can place it in the **ORDER BY** section, e.g i have a field called **RESID**, it is a numeric field, but not a primary key.

```
SELECT 
Table1.Rente_RES, Table1.Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N, Table1.Rente_RESID
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Table1.RESID;
```

Comment: `Order By` sorts the rows, not the columns

Comment: Thanks @SolaOshinowo. I'm looking to change the order of the columns as FunThomas mentioned the ORDER BY wouldn't work in this case.